# Javascript Regex multi-matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have spent time here [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and here [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) but still can't figure out how to do the following:

Example String: "input_u_s13p_11_backup_person"

What is consistent in every string: "input_u_s13p_"

```
Before: input_u_s13p_11_backup_person
After:  u_backup_person
```

```
Before: input_u_s13p_6_a_little_thing
After:  u_a_little_thing
```

```
Before: input_u_s13p_10_name
After:  u_name
```

```
Before: input_u_s13p_6_next_process_1
After:  u_next_process_1
```

Basically, I need all "input_u_s13p_" ripped out, and the "*??*" followed by it too.  ?? = 1 or 2 digit number

Comment: And what is your attempt?

Comment: input_u_s13p_\d{1,2}   is a match for what you are looking for, is that what you need?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol
var str = 'input_u_s13p_10_backup_person';
str = str.replace('input_u_s13p_', '');
str = str.replace(/[^_]*/, '');
str = 'u' + str;

Comment: @sniperd Yes, that's much better than what I had.  Thank you, your answer was perfect.

Comment: cool!  I'll throw that in as an answer and if you could accept it that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input_u_s13p_\d{1,2}
```

That should be the regex you are looking for.  Nice and simple.  The \d is numbers and the {1,2} means one or two of them

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following regex:

```
input_u_[a-z\d]+_\d{1,2}_
```

**Explanation**

- `input_u_` matches the characters `input_u_` literally (case sensitive)
- `[\w\d]+_` every digit/character string followed by a `_`
- `\d{1,2}_` one or two digits followed by a `_`

```js
var arr = ['input_u_s13p_10_backup_person', 'input_u_s13p_6_a_little_thing', 'input_u_s13p_10_name', 'input_u_s13p_6_next_process_1']; 

arr.forEach(function(str) {
    str = str.replace(/input_u_[\w\d]+_\d{1,2}_/g, ''); 
    str = 'u_' + str;
    console.log(str);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex can help you `input_(.*?_).*\d_(.*)` :

## regex demo

Comment: Very, very nice.  Thanks for the regex demo link too!